# How do I deploy Strapi frontend to Vercel?

Tags: deployment, frontend, admin, strapi, vercel

I currently have my Strapi database in Vercel Postgres. I am now trying to deploy the frontend to Vercel. I have tried to use the build folder as the root folder and add the entire project to git. I have also tried just adding the build folder to git and deploying with that. I am not sure what I am missing but I get a blank page https://strapi-two-pearl.vercel.app/. I tried following the Strapi docs about deploying just the front/admin panel https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/admin-panel-customization#deployment. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated I keep seeing that deploying the front to Vercel is possible but cannot find any examples.